# Questions about PV.<ID> syntax in ks.cfg

Tags: partition, kickstart

Here just for example:

```
part pv.01 -size=100 -grow -ondisk=/dev/sda
part pv.02 -size=300 -grow -ondisk=/dev/sdb
```

1. Is the purpose of the `PV.<ID>` usage merely used to customize the initial size of some disk?
2. How to specify the `<ID>` value of some PV ahead of time since itself would be "random" number?

Refer the following http link:
[CentOS/RHEL 7 LVM Partitioning in Kickstart?](https://serverfault.com/questions/826006/centos-rhel-7-lvm-partitioning-in-kickstart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the purpose of the PV. usage merely used to customize the initial size of some disk?

The `part` command is used to create disk partitions. The various options allow you to specify the associated block device, the size of the partition, etc. By assigning a `pv.<ID>` identifier, you are declaring that this partition will be an LVM "physical volume" (PV), and you can then use those identifiers when creating a volume group in your ks.cfg, e.g:

```
part pv.01 --size=100 --grow --ondisk=/dev/sda
part pv.02 --size=300 --grow --ondisk=/dev/sdb
volgroup vgsys pv.01 pv.02
```

> How to specify the  value of some PV ahead of time since itself would be "random" number?

**You** assign these identifiers in your Kickstart configuration file; they aren't randomly assigned nor do you need to know them "ahead of time". They only have meaning within the context of your Kickstart configuration.

You may want to read [the documentation for the `part` command](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#id46) as well as the [documentation for the `volgroup` command](https://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#id66).

Comment: So does it mean that the PV.<ID> can be any values including any letter that I want to specify ,  e.g.  PV.edu817 ？

Comment: Experimentally, yes, the `<ID>` component can be an arbitrary value (I ran a kickstart install with `part pv.foo ...`)...but why bother? The identifiers are only relevant in your kickstart.